# Open a Spry accordion panel by "onmouseover" instead of "onClick"?

Tags: javascript, html, spry

I added a spry accordion, but the panels only open if the user clicks on it. Is it possible to open a panel by mouseover? And if so how?

If you go [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/accordion_overview/), they show you how to do this using buttons, but the methods only include:

1)OpenFirstPanel()
2)OpenNextPanel()
3)OpenPreviousPanel()

Is there maybe a method I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to stumble across the [solution](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/105547). It was actually very simple. Hope this helps someone.